# Переадресация сайта через nginx

Tags: nginx

У меня сайт доступен по адресу site.com а как можно сделать что бы он был доступен по двум адресам site.com и site.com/old/ ?
и если клиент зашел на site.com/old/ то и все остальные переходы оставались по этому же адресу, т.е. при нажатии на "Главная" переходила на site.com/old/index а не на site.com/index

Сейчас я реализовал это так:

```
        location ^~ /old {
            rewrite ^/old(/.*)$ /$1 break;
... }
```

но так как раз и возникает проблема, что по адресу site.com/old/any_request у меня все открывает, но если я перехожу по любой из сылок на сайте то попадают уже на site.com/any_request

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html